# create the complete symmetric matrix by copying the lower triangular of a sparse matrix in triplet format

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

As the subject line suggests, what would be the most efficient way to copy the lower triangular part of a sparse matrix to the upper triangular part and complete the matrix entries to create the symmetric sparse matrix?

Assume that I have the triplets I, J, X for the lower triangle including the diagonal. I am reading these arrays from a commercial program and for storage space reasons, I believe, they only store the lower triangular part.

Well I will start testing different options soon, but wanted to see if someone else has experienced this before or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sparse](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html):

```
idx = I ~= J; %index of nondiagonals
result = sparse([I;J(idx)], [J;I(idx)], [X;X(idx)]);
```

Because `sparse` adds together elements in `X` that have duplicate subscripts in `I` and `J` we exclude diagonal elements when concatenating vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to appraoch this problem, which is what I usually do, is to use the following code:

```
L = sparse(I, J, X, n, n);
S = L + L' - diag(L);
```

Where `L` is the lower-triangular matrix, `S` is the required symmetric matrix, and `n` is the number of rows/columns of the full square matrix.